# How to make none blog related content dynamic in Wordpress

Tags: jquery, css

I have this none blog related static content i want to make dynamic in wordpress. How would you make this dynamic ? It should be user-friendly to edit in the admin panel.

Is it posts, custom-fields, types ? Really dont know.

The code looks like this:

```
    <ul class="ca-menu">
        <li>
            <a href="#">
                <span class="ca-icon">A</span>
                <div class="ca-content">
                    <h2 class="ca-main">Exceptional Service</h2>
                    <h3 class="ca-sub">Personalized to your needs</h3>
                </div>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">
                <span class="ca-icon">I</span>
                <div class="ca-content">
                    <h2 class="ca-main">Creative Storytelling</h2>
                    <h3 class="ca-sub">Advanced use of technology</h3>
                </div>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">
                <span class="ca-icon">C</span>
                <div class="ca-content">
                    <h2 class="ca-main">Infographical Education</h2>
                    <h3 class="ca-sub">Understanding visually</h3>
                </div>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">
                <span class="ca-icon">S</span>
                <div class="ca-content">
                    <h2 class="ca-main">Sophisticated Team</h2>
                    <h3 class="ca-sub">Professionals in action</h3>
                </div>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">
                <span class="ca-icon">d</span>
                <div class="ca-content">
                    <h2 class="ca-main">Unconditional Support</h2>
                    <h3 class="ca-sub">24/7 for you needs</h3>
                </div>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'WebSymbolsRegular';
    src: url('websymbols/websymbols-regular-webfont.eot');
    src: url('websymbols/websymbols-regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('websymbols/websymbols-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
        url('websymbols/websymbols-regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('websymbols/websymbols-regular-webfont.svg#WebSymbolsRegular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
.ca-menu{
    padding:0;
    margin:20px auto;
    width: 1020px;
}
.ca-menu li{
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    float:left;
    background: #fff;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    margin-right: 4px;
    -webkit-transition: all 300ms linear;
    -moz-transition: all 300ms linear;
    -o-transition: all 300ms linear;
    -ms-transition: all 300ms linear;
    transition: all 300ms linear;
}
.ca-menu li:last-child{
    margin-right: 0px;
}
.ca-menu li a{
    text-align: left;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    color: #333;
    position: relative;
}
.ca-icon{
    font-family: 'WebSymbolsRegular', cursive;
    font-size: 60px;
    color: #333;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #333;
    line-height: 150px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-transition: all 400ms linear;
    -moz-transition: all 400ms linear;
    -o-transition: all 400ms linear;
    -ms-transition: all 400ms linear;
    transition: all 400ms linear;
}
.ca-content{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
    top: 50%;
}
.ca-main{
    font-size: 30px;
    opacity: 0.8;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-transition: all 200ms linear;
    -moz-transition: all 200ms linear;
    -o-transition: all 200ms linear;
    -ms-transition: all 200ms linear;
    transition: all 200ms linear;
}
.ca-sub{
    text-align:center;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #666;
    line-height: 40px;
    opacity: 0.8;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%; 
    -webkit-transition: all 200ms linear;
    -moz-transition: all 200ms linear;
    -o-transition: all 200ms linear;
    -ms-transition: all 200ms linear;
    transition: all 200ms linear;
}
.ca-menu li:hover{
    background-color: #000;
}
.ca-menu li:hover .ca-icon{
    color: #ff2020;
    -webkit-animation: moveFromBottom 300ms ease;
    -moz-animation: moveFromBottom 300ms ease;
    -ms-animation: moveFromBottom 300ms ease;
}
.ca-menu li:hover .ca-main{
    color: #ff2020;
    -webkit-animation: smallToBig 300ms ease;
    -moz-animation: smallToBig 300ms ease;
    -ms-animation: smallToBig 300ms ease;
}
.ca-menu li:hover .ca-sub{
    color: #000;
    background-color: #ff2020;
    -webkit-animation: moveFromBottom 500ms ease;
    -moz-animation: moveFromBottom 500ms ease;
    -ms-animation: moveFromBottom 500ms ease;
}
@-webkit-keyframes smallToBig{
    from {
        -webkit-transform: scale(0.1);
    }
    to {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes smallToBig{
    from {
        -moz-transform: scale(0.1);
    }
    to {
        -moz-transform: scale(1);
    }
}
@-ms-keyframes smallToBig{
    from {
        -ms-transform: scale(0.1);
    }
    to {
        -ms-transform: scale(1);
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes moveFromBottom {
    from {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(100%);
    }
    to {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0%);
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes moveFromBottom {
    from {
        -moz-transform: translateY(100%);
    }
    to {
        -moz-transform: translateY(0%);
    }
}
@-ms-keyframes moveFromBottom {
    from {
        -ms-transform: translateY(100%);
    }
    to {
        -ms-transform: translateY(0%);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using [Elliot Condon's Advanced Custom Fields](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/)

Comment: So you are saying custom fields ? What about post ?

Comment: Yes I think so, custom fields are very easy to use, both for the developer and the client.  I use them in my websites all the time.
example:[link](http://www.chapeaulondon.com/post-production/) - The video carousel uses custom fields. One more example: [link](http://anticom.tv/fmegroup/) - all the little boxes on the front page of this site use custom fields